# How to check which model is using by a controller in cakephp-2.3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am facing a model association problem in cakephp-2.3. Described in [Plugin model assiciation is not working in cakephp 2.3 with cake ACL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562664/plugin-model-assiciation-is-not-working-in-cakephp-2-3)

Now it seems to me that the UsersController in not using User model. I have used

```
public $uses = array ('Cauth.User');
```

But though it seems to me that it does not using this mode. Has there any way to check which model is using my controller in cakephp-2.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) to find out if it is really using the 'User' model, or a generic 'AppModel' or 'Model';

Inside an action of your controller;

```
debug(get_class($this->User));
```

If it is a 'Model' or 'AppModel', CakePHP apparently wasn't able to locate or load your User model from the plugin.

Also check if you actually *loaded* the plugin in your bootstrap.php.

Read the documentation here: [Plugins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#installing-a-plugin)

Comment: Thanks thaJeztah. I have got my answer on this question. it is using 'AppModel' but I have loaded the plugin as described in cake doc. i.e same as contactManager example. But still it loaded from 'AppModel'. Any more help on this issue?

Comment: Hm, not really sure. Check if all files are named correctly and in the right path. It may also be worth a try to empty the `app/tmp/cache/persistent` and `app/tmp/cache/models` directories.

Comment: Thank you once again. Trying. :)